# JQuery Cycle Plugin, SIFR and PNG Fix - strange behaviour in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, png, sifr

I am using the JQuery Cycle plugin to flick through a bunch of divs with content in them.

Everything is fine in FF and Chrome but in IE 6/7 the SIFR titles do not appear in any divs apart from the first in the cycle.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?, I have notice that when I switch of the belated_png fix for IE6 everything works fine.

Is this an issue with SIFR, the Cycle Plugin or the png fix?, how could I approach this differently? maybe with all JQuery plugins i.e. JQuery Sifr, Jquery png fix etc?

Here is a test url to demonstrate the bug in action - http://fi-testing.co.uk/clients/cavendish/v2/wedding-dresses.html

Thanks in Advance for any help you can offer.

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine it has to do with IE's handling of hidden Flash content.

It would be easier to use @font-face for cross-browser font support. This is a good guide: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/

However, check the licensing on the font to make sure that using @font-face is allowed.

Comment: When all we hate IE, then I don't know for whom microsoft is developing IE, it should include firefox as a standard browser with windows.